# Getting 'import/no-anonymous-default-export' warning for named functions in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, eslint

I'm working with a React / Redux app that for some reason is getting a 'import/no-anonymous-default-export' warning for the app reducers even though the reducer functions are named.

```
userRedirect.js

import {SET_USER_REDIRECT} from "../actions/actionTypes";

const initialState = {
    active: false,
    title: '',
    messages: [],
    btnText: ''
};

const userRedirect = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_USER_REDIRECT:
            let newState = {...state};
            newState = {...newState, ...action.payload.redirectData};
            return newState;

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default userRedirect;
```

This reducer is being imported into a *index.js* that is located in a reducers folder where *userRedirect.js* is also located. It then uses *combineReducers* method from *redux* to handle the reducers.

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import userData from './userData';
import userRedirect from './userRedirect';

export default combineReducers({
    userData,
    userRedirect
});
```

This is then imported into the index of a *store* folder where this happens:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux";

import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

import rootReducer from "./../reducers";

export default createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
```

To me it seems like there is a error with the plugin or something, but I've tried *npm install*, I've tried creating the *userRedirect* reducer using a *function declaration and not a expression*, but no matter what I do it keeps showing the warning and for the life of me I cannot figure out why.

Do you guys have any ideas or suggestions in regards to this? Am I just missing something?

Much appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

[
export default combineReducers({
userData,
userRedirect
});

export default createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

These two are anonymous export.

Change it to

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
userData,
userRedirect
});

export default rootReducer;

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

export default store;

Forgive me if does not look good ... answering from mobile.
Not able to format from mobile